# Download files from FTP to shared drive

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I have an Excel macro that can pull files from a WinSCP FTP client to my local `C:\users\documents` folder, however, when I change the file path to a folder in the `G:` drive, the shell no longer runs the script created by my code automatically. My code creates the script and then I have to manually go to `cmd` and run `"ftp -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME` for the file to transfer from FTP to `G:`.

Here is my code so far, does anyone have advice on what I should do?

```
Option Explicit
Const FTP_ADDRESS = "ip address"
Const FTP_USERID = "user"
Const FTP_PASSWORD = "pw"

Sub GetFile()
    If Not GetFtpFile_F() Then
        MsgBox "Error getting ftp file"
    Else
        MsgBox "Received"
    End If
End Sub


Function GetFtpFile_F() As Boolean
    Dim rc As Integer
    Dim iFreeFile As Integer
    Dim sFTPUserID As String
    Dim sFTPPassWord As String '
    Dim sWorkingDirectory As String
    Dim sFileToGet As String

    Const FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME = "PULLSCRIPT"

    GetFtpFile_F = False

    sWorkingDirectory = "G:\...\...\folder\"
    sFileToGet = "file." & Format(Now(), "yyyyMMdd")

    On Error GoTo FtpNECAFile_EH

    'Kill FTP process file if it exists
    If Dir(sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME) <> "" Then
        Kill sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME
    End If

    'Create FTP process file
    iFreeFile = FreeFile
    Open sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME For Output As #iFreeFile
    Print #iFreeFile, "open " & FTP_ADDRESS
    Print #iFreeFile, FTP_USERID
    Print #iFreeFile, FTP_PASSWORD
    Print #iFreeFile, "cd " & FTP_USERID
    Print #iFreeFile, "mget " & sFileToGet
    Print #iFreeFile, "y"
    Print #iFreeFile, "quit"
    Close #iFreeFile

    'Shell command the FTP file to the server
    Shell "ftp -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME

    GetFtpFile_F = True

    GoTo FtpNECAFile_EX

FtpNECAFile_EH:
    MsgBox "Err", Err.Name

FtpNECAFile_EX:

    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Do you have write privileges on the drive?

Comment: Just create a fuction which moves the files from drive C: to G:

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265015(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Your code does not use WinSCP, but Windows built-in `ftp`.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked! Unrelated problem but for some reason my computer can run this code automatically (it calls Shell ftp -s... without needing me to open cmd), but when I try on a coworkers' his doesn't automatically run Shell and I have to manually open cmd and run the command

Answer (score 0):

Just Make Correction As shown Below
It worked For me hope Will work for you as well

```
 Print #iFreeFile, "open " & "111.111.1111.111"
   Print #iFreeFile, "c010@abcd.com"
   Print #iFreeFile, "********"
   Print #iFreeFile, "cd " & "/data"
   Print #iFreeFile, "lcd D:\mydata\test"
   Print #iFreeFile, "mget *.csv"
   Print #iFreeFile, "y"
   Print #iFreeFile, "close"
   Print #iFreeFile, "quit"
   Close #iFreeFile
     or 
  iFreeFile = FreeFile
    Open sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME For Output As #iFreeFile
    Print #iFreeFile, "open " & FTP_ADDRESS
    Print #iFreeFile, FTP_USERID
    Print #iFreeFile, FTP_PASSWORD
    Print #iFreeFile, "cd " & FTP_USERID

    Dim FTP_mypath As string 
    FTP_mypath ="D:\mydata\test"
    Print #iFreeFile, "lcd " & FTP_Mypath 
    Print #iFreeFile, "mget " & sFileToGet
    Print #iFreeFile, "y"
    Print #iFreeFile, "quit"
    Close #iFreeFile
```

Comment: Hi  Please Confirm The above mentioned Corrections worked for you or not